# How to set environment for gfortran as a user in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gfortran, environment

I installed gfortran as a user in a server. But I can't able to set the environment. Would someone help me with it?

I am able to use `gfortran` with the following command:

```
/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/bin/gfortran
```

I tried to set my environment with following, but not working.

```
$ vi ~/.bashrc
$ export gfortran=/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/bin/gfortran
$ source ~/.bashrc
```

When I type:

```
$ gfortran 
command not found
```

But when I type:

```
$/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/bin/gfortran
fatal error: no input file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `export` command is used to define and environment variable. What you need is called an "alias".

Add this line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

```
alias gfortran="/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/bin/gfortran"
```

Then run `source ~/.bashrc` and the `gfortran` command will execute the binary located at `/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/bin/gfortran`.

Comment: Ahhh!!! Thanks alot.. It worked now.. I spent more than 2 hours for this and searched many documents...

Comment: Would you please suggest, when I give the command `which gfortran` , it is showing `which: no gfortran in (/home/kay/libraries/)`

Comment: @Kay You might wish to add this directory to your `PATH`. For example in bash `export PATH=${PATH}:/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/bin`. You could add this to your `~/.bashrc` file. (edit: I'm guessing you'll probably also want to do something like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/home/kay/gcc-4.8.5/lib` to use any libraries provided with this install of gcc, but I could be wrong). What we're doing here is adding a new path in which to search for executables (and libraries in second case) to the existing list (that's why PATH is on the left and right).

Comment: ^ changing PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the correct answer. gfortran is more than just an alias.

Comment: @d_1999 Many thanks .. Now it is showing with `which gfortran`